# Google Sheets API v4 values.get and values.batchGet returning undefined or return value is missing for empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google Sheets API v4, `Values.get` is returning 'undefined' if the cell is empty. And `Values.get` returns `{majorDimension=ROWS, range=Sheet1!J7:L7}` without 'values' part if the cells are empty. 
Is there a way to get the following output if the cells are empty? 
`Values.get` to return `[[]]` instead of `undefined`
`Values.batchGet` to return `{majorDimension=ROWS, values=[[]], range=Sheet1!J7:L7}` instead of `{majorDimension=ROWS, range=Sheet1!J7:L7}` 
Here is the code:

```
function getOneCellValue() {
  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("SpreadsheetId", "Sheet1!L20");
  Logger.log(response.values);
}

function getValueRanges() {
  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet("SpreadsheetId", {ranges: ["Sheet1!D7:F7", "Sheet1!J7:L7"]});
  Logger.log(response.valueRanges);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sheets API `Values.get()` & `Values.batchGet()` [ValueRange: values[]](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange.FIELDS.values) discards extra rows/columns if they are empty:

> The data that was read or to be written. This is an array of arrays, the outer array representing all the data and each inner array representing a major dimension. Each item in the inner array corresponds with one cell.
>
> **For output, empty trailing rows and columns will not be included.**

If you want the value(s) to come back as empty cells, use the [built-in method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) `range.getValues()`. Or replace `undefined` with the `[[]]` value.

```
function getOneCellValue() {
  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("SpreadsheetId", "Sheet1!L20");
  
  // Assign the empty array if undefined
  var api_value = response.values || [[]];

  Logger.log(api_value);


  // Or use getValues()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var get_values = ss.getRange("Sheet1!L20").getValues();

  Logger.log(get_values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set majorDimension='COLUMNS' instead of majorDimension='ROWS'. Setting majorDimension='COLUMNS' returns placeholders where there are no values. Further information about the function arguments can be gotten [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

```
result = sheet.values().get(
                            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                            range=data_range,
                            majorDimension='COLUMNS'
                          ).execute()
```